# Dumping the crash dumps

Tags: c#, command-line, debugdiag

I need to write a tool, that listens for some target process(which crashes in customer environment) and as soon as it crashes it should generate a dump by launching DebugDiag passing it the command line parameters. The code needs to be written in C#. I have already done some coding but the tool never detects the process launched.
Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
     new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
    startWatch.EventArrived
                        += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
    startWatch.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
    startWatch.Stop();

}


    static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value as string;
        Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", name);
        if (name != null && name.Contains("My Process.exe"))
        {
            string procpath = "C:\\Program Files\\DebugDiag";
            string filename = Path.Combine(procpath, "DbgHost.exe");
            var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, "-dump My Process.exe");
        }
    }
```

Please also advise if this is the way to pass command line parameters to DebugDiag
@Bruno, i implemented your suggestion using ProcDump. Now it works once, which means when i launch my target process(32 bit) ProcDump also launches, however my application is such that when i launch a workspace within, it launches another process with the same name and this time ProcDump failed to lauch, upon debugging i found that it threw an exception saying 32-bit process cannot debug 64-bit process and all my target processes are 32-bit only...
Code:

```
static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value as string;
    Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", name);
    if (name != null && name.Contains("MyProcess.exe"))
    {
        string procpath = "C:\\Procdump";
        string filename = Path.Combine(procpath, "procdump.exe");
        var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, "-e -f -mp -n 25 -w -accepteula MyProcess.exe MyProcess_crash");
    }
}
```

Comment: Windows and DebugDiag have built in support for this () - why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I know there is a built-in support. However i cannot expect my customers to do the configuration. Instead they should be able to launch a simple .exe(i.e. my code) and do the needful. That was not the exact reason to downgrade my query. I did not intent to reinvent any wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Use Procdump.exe.
It is a complete tool developed by sysinternals that produces
dump, minidump and so on.
It is callable by command line 
See
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx